# string remover of the last value of an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 let produtos = [...Produtos, data]
           produtos= produtos.sort((a,b) => a.numero_volume - b.numero_volume)
              setFiltro('')
              var volume = data.volumes

              var list = [];

              for (var i = 1; i <= volume; i++) {
                
                const p = produtos.find(p => p.numero_volume == i)
            
                if(!p) {
                
                    list.push(`${i},`);
                  
                }
                setLista(list) 
              }
              setProdutos(produtos)
```

What returns me from this is

[image]

I need to remove the comma from the last string, remembering that the final number can be another, but it will always be the last number in ascending order

Comment: just `push(i)` and then `list.join(', ')` your array with commas

Answer (score 0):

write the comma before the number

```
let produtos = [...Produtos, data]
           produtos= produtos.sort((a,b) => a.numero_volume - b.numero_volume)
              setFiltro('')
              var volume = data.volumes

              var list = [];

              for (var i = 1; i <= volume; i++) {
                
                const p = produtos.find(p => p.numero_volume == i)
            
                if(!p) {
                
                   if(list.length === 0) list.push(`${i}`);
                   else list.push(`,${i}`)
                  
                }
                setLista(list) 
              }
              setProdutos(produtos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last comma:

```
setProdutos(produtos.replace(/,(?=\s*$)/, ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `join` instead of add a comma on every elements

like this

```
let produtos = [...Produtos, data]
produtos = produtos.sort((a, b) => a.numero_volume - b.numero_volume)
setFiltro('')
var volume = data.volumes

var list = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= volume; i++) {

  const p = produtos.find(p => p.numero_volume == i)

  if (!p) {

    list.push(i);

  }
  setLista(list.join(', '))
}
setProdutos(produtos)
```

Comment: I think you, pilchard, and I are in agreement that the list should be a list and the display of the list should be a string.. such that the items in the list should likely not be having a comma. But just to state the obvious: list.join is a string, not an array (setLista also needs to be changed)